# how to identify each individual's maximum digit span?

Tags: r

I'm trying to write a script for identifying an individual's max digit span on a standard digit span task in R and I seem to be having some trouble. Editted to include the full dataset below.

What I'm trying to do is identify the maximum number of digits in column "corrAns" that corresponds to the last "1" in column "DSAns.corr" for each initials and each session. So for example, participant #92 would have a score of 7 because their max number of correctly remembered digits is 0,3,6,1,0,4,7 (column 3, row 9).

I've written the following function for iterating through the different initials and sessions, but I'm unsure of how to write the actual statement to actually produce the digit span value that I'm looking for. Thank you in advance for any guidance!

```
i = 1 #session ID
j = 1 #participant ID

for (i in 1:2) {
  for (j in 1:length(unique(data$initials))) {
    digitspan = sum(data$DSAns.corr) #this is the line I'm having trouble with
    print(digitspan)
  }
}
```

full dataset here:

```
structure(list(session = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1), initials = c("92", "92", "92", "92", "92", "92", "92", "92", 
"92", "92", "92", "92", "92", "92", "92", "92", "88", "88", "88", 
"88", "88", "88", "88", "88", "88", "88", "88", "88", "88", "88", 
"88", "88", "88", "88", "88", "88", "88", "88", "88", "88", "23", 
"23", "23", "23", "23", "23", "23", "23", "23", "23", "23", "23", 
"23", "23", "23", "23", "23", "23", "23", "47", "47", "47", "47", 
"47", "47", "47", "47", "47", "47", "47", "47", "47", "47", "47", 
"47", "47", "47", "47", "47", "47", "87", "87", "87", "87", "87", 
"87", "87", "87", "87", "87", "87", "87", "87", "87", "87", "87", 
"87", "87", "87", "87", "87", "SW", "SW", "SW", "SW", "SW", "SW", 
"SW", "SW", "SW", "SW", "SW", "SW", "SW", "SW", "SW", "SW", "SW", 
"SW", "SW", "SW", "SW", "SW", "SW", "SW", "SW", "SW", "SW", "SW", 
"SW", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", 
"11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", 
"11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "88", "88", "88", "88", "88", 
"88", "88", "88", "88", "88", "88", "88", "88", "88", "88", "88", 
"88", "88", "88", "88", "88", "88", "88", "88", "88", "88", "88", 
"88", "88", "88", "88", "67", "67", "67", "67", "67", "67", "67", 
"67", "67", "67", "67", "67", "67", "67", "67", "67", "67", "67", 
"67", "AS", "AS", "AS", "AS", "AS", "AS", "AS", "AS", "AS", "AS", 
"AS", "AS", "90", "90", "90", "90", "90", "90", "90", "90", "90", 
"90", "90", "90", "90", "90", "90", "90", "90", "90", "90", "90", 
"90", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", 
"00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "14", "14", "14", 
"14", "14", "14", "14", "14", "14", "14", "14", "14", "14", "14", 
"14", "14", "14", "14", "14", "14", "14", "14", "14", "14", "14", 
"14", "14", "14", "14", "14", "14", "14", "14", "14", "14", "14", 
"14", "14", "14", "14", "14", "14", "14", "14", "14", "14", "14", 
"14", "14", "89", "89", "89", "89", "89", "89", "89", "89", "89", 
"89", "89", "89", "89", "89", "89", "89", "89", "23", "23", "23", 
"23", "23", "23", "23", "23", "23", "23", "23", "23", "23", "23", 
"23", "23", "23", "23", "23", "23", "92", "92", "92", "92", "92", 
"92", "92", "92", "92", "92", "92", "92", "92", "92", "14", "14", 
"14", "14", "14", "14", "14", "14", "14", "14", "14", "14", "14", 
"14", "14", "14", "14", "14", "14", "87", "87", "87", "87", "87", 
"87", "87", "87", "87", "87", "87", "87", "87", "87", "87", "87", 
"87", "87", "87", "87", "87", "47", "47", "47", "47", "47", "47", 
"47", "47", "47", "47", "47", "47", "47", "47", "47", "47", "47", 
"47", "90", "90", "90", "90", "90", "90", "90", "90", "90", "90", 
"90", "90", "90", "90", "90", "90", "67", "67", "67", "67", "67", 
"67", "67", "67", "67", "67", "67", "67", "67", "67", "67", "67", 
"67", "67", "67", "67", "67", "67"), corrAns = c("3,2,3", "1,3,1", 
"2,7,2,6", "7,2,9,0", "8,6,4,5,0", "3,6,7,4,6", "0,2,3,4,6,5", 
"2,6,8,0,1,5", "0,3,6,1,0,4,7", "2,9,7,0,6,2,0", "6,9,0,6,7,3,5,3", 
"5,8,4", "0,3,2", "0,7,1,3", "9,8,5,3", "8,7,0,9,6", "3,2,3", 
"1,3,1", "2,7,2,6", "7,2,9,0", "8,6,4,5,0", "3,6,7,4,6", "0,2,3,4,6,5", 
"2,6,8,0,1,5", "0,3,6,1,0,4,7", "5,8,4", "0,3,2", "0,7,1,3", 
"9,8,5,3", "8,7,0,9,6", "5,9,7,9,1", "5,7,8,4,7,6", "2,7,9,0,6,7", 
"5,7,5,0,8,1,6", "9,1,2,1,4,7,9", "5,1,6,9,6,2,6,1", "3,4,8,1,3,2,7,1", 
"8,5,6,0,8,4,6,0,4", "7,9,6,3,8,1,9,2,9", "2,3,2,7,1,0,2,7,4,5", 
"3,2,3", "1,3,1", "2,7,2,6", "7,2,9,0", "8,6,4,5,0", "3,6,7,4,6", 
"0,2,3,4,6,5", "2,6,8,0,1,5", "0,3,6,1,0,4,7", "2,9,7,0,6,2,0", 
"5,8,4", "0,3,2", "0,7,1,3", "9,8,5,3", "8,7,0,9,6", "5,9,7,9,1", 
"5,7,8,4,7,6", "2,7,9,0,6,7", "5,7,5,0,8,1,6", "3,2,3", "1,3,1", 
"2,7,2,6", "7,2,9,0", "8,6,4,5,0", "3,6,7,4,6", "0,2,3,4,6,5", 
"2,6,8,0,1,5", "0,3,6,1,0,4,7", "2,9,7,0,6,2,0", "5,8,4", "0,3,2", 
"0,7,1,3", "9,8,5,3", "8,7,0,9,6", "5,9,7,9,1", "5,7,8,4,7,6", 
"2,7,9,0,6,7", "5,7,5,0,8,1,6", "9,1,2,1,4,7,9", "5,1,6,9,6,2,6,1", 
"3,2,3", "1,3,1", "2,7,2,6", "7,2,9,0", "8,6,4,5,0", "3,6,7,4,6", 
"0,2,3,4,6,5", "2,6,8,0,1,5", "0,3,6,1,0,4,7", "2,9,7,0,6,2,0", 
"6,9,0,6,7,3,5,3", "7,2,9,0,7,0,1,3", "7,4,3,4,2,5,3,8,5", "3,2,5,9,3,4,5,7,1", 
"5,8,4", "0,3,2", "0,7,1,3", "9,8,5,3", "8,7,0,9,6", "5,9,7,9,1", 
"5,7,8,4,7,6", "3,2,3", "1,3,1", "2,7,2,6", "7,2,9,0", "8,6,4,5,0", 
"3,6,7,4,6", "0,2,3,4,6,5", "2,6,8,0,1,5", "0,3,6,1,0,4,7", "2,9,7,0,6,2,0", 
"6,9,0,6,7,3,5,3", "7,2,9,0,7,0,1,3", "7,4,3,4,2,5,3,8,5", "3,2,5,9,3,4,5,7,1", 
"5,1,0,2,4,1,2,9,8,2", "9,5,3,7,5,6,4,1,6,7", "1,8,4,8,8,7,6,0,3,9,5", 
"5,8,4", "0,3,2", "0,7,1,3", "9,8,5,3", "8,7,0,9,6", "5,9,7,9,1", 
"5,7,8,4,7,6", "2,7,9,0,6,7", "5,7,5,0,8,1,6", "9,1,2,1,4,7,9", 
"5,1,6,9,6,2,6,1", "3,4,8,1,3,2,7,1", "3,2,3", "1,3,1", "2,7,2,6", 
"7,2,9,0", "8,6,4,5,0", "3,6,7,4,6", "0,2,3,4,6,5", "2,6,8,0,1,5", 
"0,3,6,1,0,4,7", "2,9,7,0,6,2,0", "6,9,0,6,7,3,5,3", "7,2,9,0,7,0,1,3", 
"7,4,3,4,2,5,3,8,5", "3,2,5,9,3,4,5,7,1", "5,1,0,2,4,1,2,9,8,2", 
"5,8,4", "0,3,2", "0,7,1,3", "9,8,5,3", "8,7,0,9,6", "5,9,7,9,1", 
"5,7,8,4,7,6", "2,7,9,0,6,7", "5,7,5,0,8,1,6", "9,1,2,1,4,7,9", 
"5,1,6,9,6,2,6,1", "3,4,8,1,3,2,7,1", "3,2,3", "1,3,1", "2,7,2,6", 
"7,2,9,0", "8,6,4,5,0", "3,6,7,4,6", "0,2,3,4,6,5", "2,6,8,0,1,5", 
"0,3,6,1,0,4,7", "2,9,7,0,6,2,0", "6,9,0,6,7,3,5,3", "7,2,9,0,7,0,1,3", 
"7,4,3,4,2,5,3,8,5", "3,2,5,9,3,4,5,7,1", "5,1,0,2,4,1,2,9,8,2", 
"5,8,4", "0,3,2", "0,7,1,3", "9,8,5,3", "8,7,0,9,6", "5,9,7,9,1", 
"5,7,8,4,7,6", "2,7,9,0,6,7", "5,7,5,0,8,1,6", "9,1,2,1,4,7,9", 
"5,1,6,9,6,2,6,1", "3,4,8,1,3,2,7,1", "8,5,6,0,8,4,6,0,4", "7,9,6,3,8,1,9,2,9", 
"2,3,2,7,1,0,2,7,4,5", "6,0,7,8,4,3,4,0,5,8", "3,2,3", "1,3,1", 
"2,7,2,6", "7,2,9,0", "8,6,4,5,0", "3,6,7,4,6", "0,2,3,4,6,5", 
"2,6,8,0,1,5", "0,3,6,1,0,4,7", "2,9,7,0,6,2,0", "6,9,0,6,7,3,5,3", 
"7,2,9,0,7,0,1,3", "5,8,4", "0,3,2", "0,7,1,3", "9,8,5,3", "8,7,0,9,6", 
"5,9,7,9,1", "5,7,8,4,7,6", "3,2,3", "1,3,1", "5,8,4", "0,3,2", 
"0,7,1,3", "9,8,5,3", "8,7,0,9,6", "5,9,7,9,1", "5,7,8,4,7,6", 
"2,7,9,0,6,7", "5,7,5,0,8,1,6", "9,1,2,1,4,7,9", "3,2,3", "1,3,1", 
"2,7,2,6", "7,2,9,0", "8,6,4,5,0", "3,6,7,4,6", "0,2,3,4,6,5", 
"2,6,8,0,1,5", "0,3,6,1,0,4,7", "2,9,7,0,6,2,0", "6,9,0,6,7,3,5,3", 
"7,2,9,0,7,0,1,3", "7,4,3,4,2,5,3,8,5", "3,2,5,9,3,4,5,7,1", 
"5,1,0,2,4,1,2,9,8,2", "5,8,4", "0,3,2", "0,7,1,3", "9,8,5,3", 
"8,7,0,9,6", "5,9,7,9,1", "3,2,3", "1,3,1", "2,7,2,6", "7,2,9,0", 
"8,6,4,5,0", "3,6,7,4,6", "0,2,3,4,6,5", "2,6,8,0,1,5", "0,3,6,1,0,4,7", 
"2,9,7,0,6,2,0", "5,8,4", "0,3,2", "0,7,1,3", "9,8,5,3", "8,7,0,9,6", 
"5,9,7,9,1", "5,7,8,4,7,6", "2,7,9,0,6,7", "3,2,3", "1,3,1", 
"2,7,2,6", "7,2,9,0", "8,6,4,5,0", "3,6,7,4,6", "0,2,3,4,6,5", 
"2,6,8,0,1,5", "0,3,6,1,0,4,7", "2,9,7,0,6,2,0", "5,8,4", "0,3,2", 
"0,7,1,3", "9,8,5,3", "8,7,0,9,6", "5,9,7,9,1", "5,7,8,4,7,6", 
"2,7,9,0,6,7", "3,2,3", "1,3,1", "2,7,2,6", "7,2,9,0", "8,6,4,5,0", 
"3,6,7,4,6", "0,2,3,4,6,5", "2,6,8,0,1,5", "0,3,6,1,0,4,7", "2,9,7,0,6,2,0", 
"6,9,0,6,7,3,5,3", "7,2,9,0,7,0,1,3", "7,4,3,4,2,5,3,8,5", "3,2,5,9,3,4,5,7,1", 
"5,1,0,2,4,1,2,9,8,2", "9,5,3,7,5,6,4,1,6,7", "1,8,4,8,8,7,6,0,3,9,5", 
"8,3,3,6,0,9,8,2,7,6,0", "5,8,4", "0,3,2", "0,7,1,3", "9,8,5,3", 
"8,7,0,9,6", "5,9,7,9,1", "5,7,8,4,7,6", "2,7,9,0,6,7", "5,7,5,0,8,1,6", 
"9,1,2,1,4,7,9", "5,1,6,9,6,2,6,1", "3,4,8,1,3,2,7,1", "8,5,6,0,8,4,6,0,4", 
"3,2,3", "1,3,1", "2,7,2,6", "7,2,9,0", "8,6,4,5,0", "3,6,7,4,6", 
"0,2,3,4,6,5", "2,6,8,0,1,5", "0,3,6,1,0,4,7", "5,8,4", "0,3,2", 
"0,7,1,3", "9,8,5,3", "8,7,0,9,6", "5,9,7,9,1", "5,7,8,4,7,6", 
"2,7,9,0,6,7", "3,2,3", "1,3,1", "2,7,2,6", "7,2,9,0", "8,6,4,5,0", 
"3,6,7,4,6", "0,2,3,4,6,5", "2,6,8,0,1,5", "0,3,6,1,0,4,7", "2,9,7,0,6,2,0", 
"6,9,0,6,7,3,5,3", "7,2,9,0,7,0,1,3", "5,8,4", "0,3,2", "0,7,1,3", 
"9,8,5,3", "8,7,0,9,6", "5,9,7,9,1", "5,7,8,4,7,6", "2,7,9,0,6,7", 
"3,2,3", "1,3,1", "2,7,2,6", "7,2,9,0", "8,6,4,5,0", "3,6,7,4,6", 
"0,2,3,4,6,5", "2,6,8,0,1,5", "5,8,4", "0,3,2", "0,7,1,3", "9,8,5,3", 
"8,7,0,9,6", "5,9,7,9,1", "3,2,3", "1,3,1", "2,7,2,6", "7,2,9,0", 
"8,6,4,5,0", "3,6,7,4,6", "0,2,3,4,6,5", "2,6,8,0,1,5", "0,3,6,1,0,4,7", 
"5,8,4", "0,3,2", "0,7,1,3", "9,8,5,3", "8,7,0,9,6", "5,9,7,9,1", 
"5,7,8,4,7,6", "2,7,9,0,6,7", "5,7,5,0,8,1,6", "9,1,2,1,4,7,9", 
"3,2,3", "1,3,1", "2,7,2,6", "7,2,9,0", "8,6,4,5,0", "3,6,7,4,6", 
"0,2,3,4,6,5", "2,6,8,0,1,5", "0,3,6,1,0,4,7", "2,9,7,0,6,2,0", 
"6,9,0,6,7,3,5,3", "7,2,9,0,7,0,1,3", "5,8,4", "0,3,2", "0,7,1,3", 
"9,8,5,3", "8,7,0,9,6", "5,9,7,9,1", "5,7,8,4,7,6", "2,7,9,0,6,7", 
"5,7,5,0,8,1,6", "3,2,3", "1,3,1", "2,7,2,6", "7,2,9,0", "8,6,4,5,0", 
"3,6,7,4,6", "0,2,3,4,6,5", "2,6,8,0,1,5", "0,3,6,1,0,4,7", "2,9,7,0,6,2,0", 
"6,9,0,6,7,3,5,3", "7,2,9,0,7,0,1,3", "7,4,3,4,2,5,3,8,5", "5,8,4", 
"0,3,2", "0,7,1,3", "9,8,5,3", "8,7,0,9,6", "3,2,3", "1,3,1", 
"2,7,2,6", "7,2,9,0", "8,6,4,5,0", "3,6,7,4,6", "0,2,3,4,6,5", 
"2,6,8,0,1,5", "0,3,6,1,0,4,7", "2,9,7,0,6,2,0", "5,8,4", "0,3,2", 
"0,7,1,3", "9,8,5,3", "8,7,0,9,6", "5,9,7,9,1", "3,2,3", "1,3,1", 
"2,7,2,6", "7,2,9,0", "8,6,4,5,0", "3,6,7,4,6", "0,2,3,4,6,5", 
"2,6,8,0,1,5", "0,3,6,1,0,4,7", "2,9,7,0,6,2,0", "6,9,0,6,7,3,5,3", 
"7,2,9,0,7,0,1,3", "5,8,4", "0,3,2", "0,7,1,3", "9,8,5,3", "8,7,0,9,6", 
"5,9,7,9,1", "5,7,8,4,7,6", "2,7,9,0,6,7", "5,7,5,0,8,1,6", "9,1,2,1,4,7,9"
), DSAns.corr = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 0, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, 0, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
0, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA), DSAns_2.corr = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 0, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, NA, NA, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 0, 
1, 1, 0, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 1, 0, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 
1, 0, 1, 0, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -454L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x000001a95b0e1ef0>)
```

Comment: Pictures for data are not a good way to get a response from potential answerers. Instead learn to use `dput` to create a text version of your R objects that you can paste into a question and we can paste into our consoles. Otherwise you are implying that we a) know the variable types (which are often ambiguous from the print output), and b) that it is our responsibility to redo the data entry.

Answer (score 4):

Flying blind here w/o reproducible data, but I think this would work:

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%

  # select last row of each user session with DNAns.corr == 1
  group_by(session, initials) %>%
  filter(DSAns.corr == 1) %>%
  slice_tail(n = 1) %>%   # EDIT: corrected from (1) to (n=1)
  ungroup() %>%

  # Count commas in corrAns plus 1    = # of comma-sep values
  #  (I'm assuming if zero correct it wouldn't make it through filter above)
  mutate(digitspan = stringr::str_count(corrAns, ',') + 1)
```

Comment: I'm sorry I did not include any reproducible data here (it's been edited), I'm sort of new to this programming community, but I just wanted to post to say your solution worked for me! The only change is that slice_tail() needs to be "n = 1", instead of just "1", otherwise it will throw an error message. I'm not able to upvote your solution because I need >15 reputation points(?), but thank you so much for your help!